# For what functions is this theorem correct?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-verification

**Theorem**$_0$: If $g:\mathbb{C}^k \to \mathbb{C}^k$ sends $(t a_1,...,t a_k)$ to $(t^{\alpha_1}b_1,...,t^{\alpha_k}b_k)$ for all $t\in \mathbb{C}$, the preimage of any point has size $\alpha_1 \cdots \alpha_k.$ Here $(a_1,...,a_k),(b_1,...,b_k)$ are some vectors in $\mathbb{C}^k$

Question 1: for what $g$ is this theorem true (or a slight rewording of the theorem, for instance concerning the preimage of $0$ or something like that)?

Question 2: with this adjustment to the theorem, why is it true?

Comment: In addition to the zero problem, $g$ must be injective.

Comment: I assume that the $b_i$'s depend on the $a_i$'s (otherwise the definition is not well-defined, except for zero).

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Also, the theorem is false on the axes of $C^k$, so you'll need to restrict the domain.

Comment: What's the size of a point?

Comment: @joriki How is that relevant?

Comment: @Alyosha: Well, it says "the preimage of any point has size $\alpha_1 \cdots \alpha_k$" -- I guess you wrote that because it's relevant? So it seems it would be relevant that we understand what it means.

Comment: @joriki Apologies, I meant preimage of an element in the image. I thought you were being sarcastic.

Comment: But now I still don't know what you mean by "size". My problem wasn't with "point"; it was clear enough that a point with a preimage has to be an element in the image -- but what is this notion of "size" you're using?

Comment: @joriki The cardinality. One of the conditions for the theorem to be true is surely that preimages are finite.